# what is the difference between a calculated column and a measure?

Tags: powerbi

Could you please help me understand the conceptual difference?

When do we use one over the other and how they are included in the data model?

Comment: Read: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measures, calculated columns and calculated tables all use **Data Analysis Expressions** (DAX).

1. **Calculated columns** work in the **horizontal** direction of a table
   and they add a value to each **row** of the table that can later be used
   for filtering, e.g. on the axis of a diagram.
2. **Measures** work in the **vertical** direction of a table since they aggregate or summarize the values in a **column**. They are typically the contents of a diagram.

Both **calculated columns** and **tables** will add data to the model, just like the M-code in PowerQuery does. This data is recalculated on model refresh and otherwise won't change. In contrast **measures** add formulas only that will be calulated depending on the filter context.

Comment: From the link of @David: "One important concept that you need to remember about calculated columns is that they are computed during the database processing and then stored in the model. This might seem strange if you are accustomed to SQL-computed columns – not persisted – which are computed at query time and do not use memory. In data models for DAX, however, all calculated columns occupy space in memory and are computed during table processing." Does this mean that data are actually added?

Comment: Yes.  Calculated Columns and Calculated Tables are stored in the model.  Measures are not stored, and are calculated at runtime based on the current filter context.

Comment: Makes sense. Calculated columns and tables are stored in the data model and recalculated on data refresh only. Otherwise they won't change.

Comment: Thank you guys. Got it.